# What method can I use to add a checkbox to all items in a table treeview in python tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview, ttk

I am using a tkinter treeview to display a pandas dataframe which receives data from a csv file and would like to add a checkbox to each row in the table that has an entry (or just in the task name cell). I have created a sample using the code from my main project:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import pandas as pd

base = tk.Tk()
base.geometry(f"{1000}x{500}")


# frame for treeview
treeview_frame = tk.Frame(base, width=800, height=400)
treeview_frame.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor="c")

# setup treeview display
task_treeview = ttk.Treeview(treeview_frame, columns=(1,2,3,4),show="headings")
task_treeview.place(relx=0.5,rely=0.5,relwidth=1,relheight=1,anchor="c")
task_treeview.heading("1",text="Task Name")
task_treeview.column("1", width=150)
task_treeview.heading("2",text="Task User")
task_treeview.column("2", width=150)
task_treeview.heading("3",text="Status")
task_treeview.column("3", width=100)
task_treeview.heading("4",text="Due Date")
task_treeview.column("4", width=100)

# insert task list csv into treeview
def insert_csv():

    # create dataframe
    df = pd.read_csv('task_list.csv')
    task_treeview.delete(*task_treeview.get_children())

    for i in df.index:
        task_treeview.insert("", i, values=(df.at[i, "taskname"], df.at[i, "user"], df.at[i, "status"],df.at[i, "duedate"]))

insert_csv()

tk.mainloop()
```

I have tried using the CheckboxTreeview from ttkwidgets but I believe that doesn't show the checkbox with the grid format I'm using.